# OpenGL code runnable on x86 CPU?

Tags: opengl, x86, opencl

I understand that AMD created an alternative [implementation](http://tech-beta.slashdot.org/story/09/08/06/1714233/amds-opencl-allows-gpu-code-to-run-on-x86-cpus) of OpenCL that runs on x86 CPUs. This is very useful from the standpoint of simplified debugging. Unfortunately, OpenCL isn't an option for me.

Are there any Open **GL** x86 implementations in existence? This would greatly ease my development process, at the cost of some CPU time, of course. I would then run the same code on a GPU, later, with no changes necessary.

Comment: [MESA](http://www.mesa3d.org/faq.html)? It might not support all the features you want, though.

Comment: @Michael, Nice! I'd heard of it but didn't know what it was. But... Ohhhh... only OpenGL 3.1 and I'm targetting 3.2 Core Profile. :/ Still, a possibility perhaps...

Comment: @Michael, That was an error on their page. Looking [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/docs/GL3.txt), it supports up to 3.3. If you could post this as an answer, I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/intro.html) might be an option for you.

From their website:

> Mesa is the OpenGL implementation for several types of hardware made by Intel, AMD and NVIDIA, plus the VMware virtual GPU. **There's also several software-based renderers: swrast (the legacy Mesa rasterizer), softpipe (a gallium reference driver) and llvmpipe (LLVM/JIT-based high-speed rasterizer).**

When using Mesa you can set the `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE` environment variable, which will cause Mesa to *"always use software rendering"*.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is not an instruction set, neither is it a library. It's a drawing API for interfacing with GPUs (yes there are software based rasterizers like Mesa softpipe). Most computers you can find these days support OpenGL.

When you use the OpenGL API it's not like your OpenGL calls get "translated" into a special instruction set for the GPU that's then part of your program. OpenGL operations will just create calls that eventually end up in a device driver, just like reading or writing to a file.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment. Thanks, however, for your many _useful_ OpenGL answers on SO, one of which I upvoted today.

Comment: @NickWiggill: Sorry, but it's hard to make you what you question was in the first place. You're asking about x86 OpenGL implementations. Well yes, there are. Every GPU driver that's intended for the x86 architecture is such a implementation. You're talking about debugging, but you're not telling what you want to debug at all. Also you should consider OpenGL to be a black box. Say you're using "Mesa softpipe" for debugging purposes: What is it you want to learn about *your* program using that implementation?

Comment: "Every GPU driver that's intended for the x86 architecture is such a implementation". You're quite right. But they require more than just an x86 CPU -- they also require a GPU which will play ball with that x86 system. So I can see where the confusion came in. I was essentially asking for a software implementation. Re debugging, two aspects: GPU OpenGL may report, but doesn't spit out the data unless requested. Mesa can be made to do this with a single switch. Secondly, I want to more easily have insight into what values shaders are producing. TBF, I am not sure if Mesa can provide for this.

Comment: @NickWiggill: You still didn't specify what it is you're actually trying to get at! If it's debugging or profiling, a OpenGL debugger-profiler might be the better choice for you. There's gDEBugger and Valve Software recently released their in-house development at open source: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/vogl –– The inner workings of the particular OpenGL implementations may strongly differ between implementations. Yes, looking into a software implementation can be interesting, but you learn hardly anything about how it interacts on the target platform.